# Adobe animate : scene was not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, adobe-animate

if my output says that

```
"Attempting to launch and connect to player using URL .... after decompression.
    ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene materi was not found.
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
    at Untitled_1_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToScene_3()[Untitled_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:7]
Cannot display source code at this location.
Debug session terminated."
```

What should i do to fix it?

Comment: First [research the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=as3+error+%232108) (maybe the AS3 manual itself or some article has a working solution). **(2)** Your problem might be related to putting different codes in different frames and scenes (some access to meaning of `materi` is being lost). Best solution is to keep all content and code on frame 1 if typing on timeline. You can use a MClip to be container (of your content) whose own frames and scenes can change. Never move the main Stage to a different frame. MovieClip is a type of mini Stage with its own timeline. Use it to your advantage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.